# What's the right way to replicating "having" in data table?

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to filter on grouped data with data table

Let's say my data was this

```
library(data.table)
mtcars[ ,.(cars = n()), .(cyl)]
```

And let's say that I wanted to only get the groups that have 3 or more cars

This is one way to do it

```
mtcars[ ,.(cars = n()), .(cyl)][cars > 3]
```

Is that the right way to do it?

Comment: You forgot the first `,`  in your data.table, but @denis edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `dplyr` (`n()`) with `data.table` (`.N`). The solution is:

```
library(data.table)
mtcars <- setDT(copy(mtcars))
mtcars[ ,.(cars = .N), .(cyl)][cars > 3]
```

Comment: Is that the official way to do having in data table?

Comment: I do not know what "to do having" means